# How do I find the first instance if the length of the elements are the same?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to solve the below problem without any functional programming.

Question: Write a function called `findShortestWordAmongMixedElements()`.

Given an array, `findShortestWordAmongMixedElements()` returns the shortest string within the given array.

Notes:

- If there are ties, it should return the first element to appear in the given array.
- Expect the given array to have values other than strings.
- If the given array is empty, it should return an empty string.
- If the given array contains no strings, it should return an empty string.

> var output = findShortestWordAmongMixedElements([4, 'two', 2, 'three']);
>   console.log(output); // --> 'two'

This is my answer so far:

```
function findShortestWordAmongMixedElements(arr) {
  // your code here
  var shortestString = '';
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
      if (typeof arr[i] === 'string' ) {
        var length = arr[i].length;
        if (arr[i].length < shortestString.length) {
          shortestString = arr[i];
        } else {
          shortestString = arr[length.indexOf(arr[i].length)];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return shortestString;
}
```

or perhaps I should have done it this way:

```
function findShortestWordAmongMixedElements(arr) {
  // your code here
  var shortestString = '';
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
      if (typeof arr[i] === 'string' ) {
        var length = arr[i].length;
        if (arr[i].length < shortestString.length) {
          shortestString = arr[i];
        } 
        if (arr[i].length === shortestString.length) {
          shortestString = arr[length.indexOf(arr[i].length)];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return shortestString;
}
```

Nothing prints out in the 2nd function. Is my `indexOf` not correct?

Comment: what is the problem you're having?

Comment: `If there are ties, it should return the first element to appear in the given array` So when comparing strings only replace the current one if the compared one is less length. If it is a tie, don't do the swap. I don't see where the confusion lies. If there is a problem with the code you posted please explain the problem and ask a question.

Comment: That `else` clause looks really suspicious. Try adding a boolean variable for "string found". You are trying to use `shortestString` as the value of the shortest string and the boolean that says a string has been encountered in the array.

Comment: The error I am getting is TypeError: length.indexOf is not a function. I am  trying to return the first instance if there is a tie.

Comment: "Given an array, "findShortestWordAmongMixedElements" returns the shortest string within the given array." doesn't mean it is a word. The whole problem is made of conflicting motions and demands

Answer (score 0):

```
function findShortestWordAmongMixedElements (arr) {
  return arr.filter(d => typeof d == 'string').sort(d => -d.length)[0] || ''
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do this without using filter nor reduce.

Comment: May be you should mention it in the question then.